# Generate price from item selected in drop down

Tags: commerce

I am using Drupal 7.14, Commerce 7.x 1.3 and Views 7.x 3.3.
I want to have a drop down list on my product display form (or content display form) containing, say:

Full Price, no coach required - £ 200
Full Price, Glasgow coach - £ 230
Full Price, Edinburgh coach - £ 230
Full Price, Liverpool coach - £220
....

and I want, when an item on the list is selected, the displayed price to change to the indicated value and, of course, this to be passed to the cart.

How can I do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the Rules module: http://drupal.org/project/rules/.  That should already be up and running if you're using Drupal Commerce.

So just go to admin/config/workflow/rules and add a new rule that looks something like this:

1. **Event**: Calculating the sell price of a product
2. **Condition**: Entity has field: [commerce-line-item], Field:
3. **Action**: Set the unit price to a specific amount; Parameter: [commerce_line_item]; Value:  can either select another field to base this on or do a hard-coded value; Leave Price component type and Price rounding mode to their defaults
4. Test!

Let me know if this ends up working for you

Comment: Thanks so much, Boriana, for your very quick reply. Will try out your suggestions and get back to you.

Comment: Have go to the setting of the Action, but I don't know how to do this.  Have defined an additional field in the product type (booking_type) which is a drop down list with allowed values (key|value) How can I specify this as the value?

Comment: Under the 'Amount' section of that action, try expanding the 'Data selectors' section, and you'll see all the fields that you can use.  Just copy and paste the one that matches your drop down list... but if your drop down list contains text (vs. an Amount), that won't work very well.  Test it out.